# Entity framework issue "The table/view ' does not have a primary key defined."

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. I am using an existing database and a table doesn't have primary key defined. When I use Entity Framework, I get the error "The table/view ' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.". I looked up a few stack overflow solutions / google, I still have some questions,

1. Doesnt EF use the identity column
2. I am sceptical about adding primary key to the table as it might affect upstream / downstream processes.
3. Alternatives / suggestions please?

Thanks,

Comment: what is the name of the table and can you show your model class?

Answer (score 12):

I've found a workaround in Davis blog (link below) to supress this error, I'll paste it here.
http://www.ericsdavis.net/index.php/2009/03/14/entity-framework-and-primary-key-inference/

1. Close the model designer in Visual Studio if it is still open and
   re-open the .edmx file in an XML editor;
2. Find the edmx:StorageModels -> Schema -> Entity Container ->
   EntitySet element that refers to the table in question;
3. On the EntitySet element, rename the store:Schema attribute to
   Schema; Remove the store:Name attribute altogether;
4. Remove the opening and closing DefiningQuery tags and everything in
   between them;

Save and close the .edmx file.

It worked like a charm for me, hope it helps.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Moreover when I opened the edmx doc in an XML editor I read this line of auto generated comment right next to the <entitytype> objects. It said `(<!--Errors Found During Generation:
warning 6002: The table/view SOME_SCHEMA.SOME_TABLE' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.-->`. I thought this indicates the kind of issue that we are facing. I think what @BrunoC fix does is it removes the mentioned inferences of the auto generated comment.

Comment: For a project I was working on, the warning generated by CSC.Exe indicating that the Entity class would be treated as a readonly view since a Primary Key was not defined made sense.  However, to keep the build output messages clear and understandable, I just added the Suppress Warning ID for 6002 (Warning 602 does not have a primary key defined) by following the steps for modifying the EF Model's parent project build settings in "How to: Suppress compiler warnings" at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings.  I hope this was of help and interest.

Comment: Implementing this fix causes the Diagram to not display any more. Closes the diagram if you are in it (once the file is changed and the the .edmx file is reloaded. For EntityFramework 6 in Visual Studio 2022.(I am also using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework ver 21.9.0.)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is tell your POCO what column to use as primary key.
If your table has an IDENTITY column then tell it to use that.

```
[Table("POCOS")]
class POCO {
    [Key]
    int theIdentityColumn {get;set;}
{
```

Answer (score 0):

In entityframework if you want to assign primary key on any column write [Key] on that property of class.

```
public class Student
    {

        [Key]
        public int StudentKey { get; set; }

        public string StudentName { get; set; }

    }
and in Entityframework you donot write any thing just use Below class that create automatic Primarykey 

 Class student
    {
    public int id {get;set}
    public string Name {get;set}
    }
more detail why should this happen read below article
[Entity Framework][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues when I was creating a view to use in my project.
After creation, I updated by `.edmx` and the same error about

> The table/view ' does not have a primary key defined.

I cleaned my solution, rebuilt, closed Visual Studio and started it again.
After that I repeated the process with cleaning and rebuilding the solution, and the error disappeared.

Comment: This is certainly not the standard way to solve this issue. Restarting VS doesn't magically add a primary key to a table in the database.

Comment: This work sometimes. I had tor clean, rebuild and close solution after I added the [Key] annotation. Not ideal though.

Comment: you have to add primary key constraint to your view, entity framework will not import your view if it is haven't a primary key.

Comment: As soon as you open the .edmx file again, the warnings come back too